# Regular expression - return split matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the code:

```
<?php

$pattern = '~(?(?=hello 2)(hello 2)|hello (1))~';


$subjects = [];
$subjects[] = <<<EOD
test hello 2 test
EOD;


$subjects[] = <<<EOD
test hello 1 test
EOD;


$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subjects[0], $matches);
assert($matches[1][0] == 'hello 2');

$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subjects[1], $matches);
assert($matches[1][0] == '1');
```

I want have all matches in one array - 2 items in array (input string, result from first or second expression), but now I get 3 items of array (input string, result, empty) or (input string, empty, result). In var dump it is:

**Actual state:**

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "hello 2"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "hello 2"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "hello 1"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

**I want:**

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "hello 2"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "hello 2"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "hello 1"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: In this simple case, you can turn the conditional pattern into branch reset `~(?|(?=hello 2)(hello 2)|hello (1))~`. If this is part of a larger pattern (and the pattern is not as simple), then you need to repeat the condition, but negated, in the second branch. `~(?|(?=hello 2)(hello 2)|(?!hello 2)hello (1))~`

Comment: Perfectly, thanks @nhahtdh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a *branch reset* with `?|`:

```
$pattern = '~(?|(?=hello 2)(hello 2)|hello (1))~';
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/sSwDbv)

With this, you will avoid non-participating groups to appear as part of the resulting match array.

See [*Branch Reset Groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) at regular-expressions.info for more details.

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly. Do you know if exists something similiar for JavaScript?

Comment: :) I know several look-behind workarounds and a conditional expression workaround, but as for branch resets... have not heard of any.